# Why ArrayDeque supports random deletion using remove(Object o)?

Tags: java, collections, arraydeque

ArrayDeque should only be supporting insertion and deletion only at the ends, that is, both at front and rear ends. If an element can be removed from in between the queue, isn't it violating the default behaviour of a Queue?

Comment: A `Queue` is a `Collection`. And `Collection.remove(Object)` must be implemented.

Comment: Therefore, it isn't violating the `Queue` contract!

Comment: A queue (little q) is an abstract data structure which supports adding and removing from both ends. There is nothing to say that an implementation can't support removing from the middle, provided it supports removing from the end *as well*.

Answer (score 0):

There is difference between `poll`(which should be used for accessing the queue) and `remove`(which is used to remove the object from collection,which is defined by Collection interface)